# From Widgets to HTML (UiBinder)

Tags: html, uibinder

I worked with uibinder based on widgets for a couple of weeks. Now i want to try out uibinder with html. I integrated  my widgets based uibinders into each other, using

```
xmlns:my="urn:import:com.wn.webapp.client.UiBinder"
<my:TopMenu/>
```

How can I do this, when I'm working with html uibinders? When I tried the same, I got an error:

> ```
>   [ERROR] [webapp] - Not allowed in an HTML context: <my:TopMenu> (:23)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

xmlns:my="urn:import:com.wn.webapp.client" (just declare the package where TopMenu is)

Comment: but leave off ".UiBinder". Can you include the full XML/java uibinder files for TopMenu and the place where you are using it?